# How to use Service in Global-interceptor in NEST Js

Tags: javascript, typescript, interceptor, nestjs

I want to use service in global interceptor.

my code look like this :

```
import { VariablesService } from '../app/modules/variables/variables.service';

@Interceptor()
export class globalInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private service: VariablesService) {
    console.log('contructor running', service);  //getting null here
  }
```

and on **server.ts** first i was initializing like this :

```
app.useGlobalInterceptors(new globalInterceptor())
```

but after the injection of service i have to do some modification because parameters are needed now in `globalInterceptor()`

```
const variableService = await app.get<VariablesService>(VariablesService);
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new globalInterceptor(variableService));
```

Now what the problem is I am getting `service` is `null` and I am unable to create the object of the service.

[GitHub issue link](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/731)

Answer (score 13):

You can register a global interceptor directly from the module definition:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_INTERCEPTOR } from '@nestjs/core';

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: GlobalInterceptor,
    },
  ],
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```

This is listed in the official documentation, [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors).

Answer (score 0):

> After that you must import VariablesService module in your current interceptor module for dipendancy injection

```js
constructor(@Inject(VariablesService) private service: VariablesService) {
    console.log('contructor running', service);  //
}
```