# NestJS: How to setup ClassSerializerInterceptor as global interceptor

Tags: interceptor, nestjs

I'm using in every Controller code like `@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)` so I decided make it global and was trying to setup it with no luck.

I was trying without and with `new` and ended up with something like this totally not working.

`app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ClassSerializerInterceptor(new Reflector()));`

I checked NestJS source code and I assume that it cannot be used as global but it should.

Comment: Did you make it work? I'm also not finding a way of making it work. I tried `app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ClassSerializerInterceptor(app.get(Reflector)));
`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Have you tried using this line of code:

```js
app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ClassSerializerInterceptor(app.get(Reflector)));
```

Comment: won't work cause `ClassSerializerInterceptor` needs proper constructor argument to be provided

Comment: Alright it's true ! The `ClassSerializerInterceptor` needs a `Reflector` instance to be instantiated properly

Comment: @G.Bar I updated my answer, maybe it suits your case. Let me know.

Answer (score 20):

I do prefer injecting global interceptors inside `app.modules.ts` instead.

Global interceptors registered from outside of any module with `useGlobalInterceptors()` cannot inject dependencies since this is done outside the context of any module.

```js
import { ClassSerializerInterceptor, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_INTERCEPTOR } from '@nestjs/core';

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: ClassSerializerInterceptor,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Reference:

[How to use Service in Global-interceptor in NEST Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50503996/how-to-use-service-in-global-interceptor-in-nest-js)

https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#binding-interceptors

Comment: I feel like this should be the preferred answer...

Answer (score 1):

Same With options:

```
import { ClassSerializerInterceptor, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_INTERCEPTOR } from '@nestjs/core';

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      inject: [Reflector],
      useFactory: (reflector: Reflector) => {
        return new ClassSerializerInterceptor(reflector, {
          enableImplicitConversion: true,
          excludeExtraneousValues: true,
        });
      },
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```